# Сколько грамматических основ в стихотворении?

Tags: синтаксис, сказуемые, сложное-предложение, подлежащее

> Буря мглою небо кроет,
>   Вихри снежные крутя;
>   То, как зверь, она завоет,
>   То заплачет, как дитя,
>   То по кровле обветшалой
>   Вдруг соломой зашумит,
>   То, как путник запоздалый,
>   К нам в окошко застучит.

Сколько грамматических основ в стихотворении? Я думаю, что 5, но такого варианта нет.
Я выделила следующие: буря кроет, она завоет, заплачет, зашумит, путник застучит.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Две основы.

Буря  кроет - 1.

То она завоет, То заплачет, То  зашумит, То застучит. - 2.

Comment: По-моему, союз "то..., то" не входит в состав сказуемого. 

Основа: она завоет, заплачет, зашумит, застучит.

Comment: Конечно,союзы не входят в член предложения, это средство связи, просто  я проиллюстрировала, что это однородные члены.

Comment: Все ясно теперь..спасибо огромное.